# BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'simpleMeterRegistry' is thrown on adding eureka server to spring boot Applicatio

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, netflix-eureka

I am just trying to learn spring microservices with reference to udemy course. So as part of exercise i was trying to create and run a component with eureka server but I am not able to run application because of following error: UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'webMvcMetricsFilter'.

Since I am new to spring boot and eureka server can anyone help me in identifying the mistake I am doing here due to which applcation fails.

Following are the details related to application:

**Spring boot logs:**

```
020-05-19 11:51:38.457  INFO 25168 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2020-05-19 11:51:38.471 ERROR 25168 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:156) ~[spring-boot-2.1.14.RELEASE.jar:2.1.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543) ~[spring-context-5.1.15.RELEASE.jar:5.1.15.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141) ~[spring-boot-2.1.14.RELEASE.jar:2.1.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:744) [spring-boot-2.1.14.RELEASE.jar:2.1.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:391) [spring-boot-2.1.14.RELEASE.jar:2.1.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:312) [spring-boot-2.1.14.RELEASE.jar:2.1.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) [spring-boot-2.1.14.RELEASE.jar:2.1.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1204) [spring-boot-2.1.14.RELEASE.jar:2.1.14.RELEASE]
    at com.srik.namingservereureka.NamingServerEurekaApplication.main(NamingServerEurekaApplication.java:25) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:124) ~[spring-boot-2.1.14.RELEASE.jar:2.1.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.<init>(TomcatWebServer.java:86) ~[spring-boot-2.1.14.RELEASE.jar:2.1.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getTomcatWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:416) ~[spring-boot-2.1.14.RELEASE.jar:2.1.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:180) ~[spring-boot-2.1.14.RELEASE.jar:2.1.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:180) ~[spring-boot-2.1.14.RELEASE.jar:2.1.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:153) ~[spring-boot-2.1.14.RELEASE.jar:2.1.14.RELEASE]
    ... 8 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'webMvcMetricsFilter' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/metrics/web/servlet/WebMvcMetricsAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'webMvcMetricsFilter' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'simpleMeterRegistry' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/metrics/export/simple/SimpleMetricsExportAutoConfiguration.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/collect/Lists
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:769) ~[spring-beans-5.1.15.RELEASE.jar:5.1.15.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:509) ~[spring-beans-5.1.15.RELEASE.jar:5.1.15.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.15.RELEASE.jar:5.1.15.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1159) ~[spring-beans-5.1.15.RELEASE.jar:5.1.15.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) ~[spring-beans-5.1.15.RELEASE.jar:5.1.15.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) ~[spring-beans-5.1.15.RELEASE.jar:5.1.15.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.15.RELEASE.jar:5.1.15.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226) ~[spring-beans-5.1.15.RELEASE.jar:5.1.15.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.15.RELEASE.jar:5.1.15.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:204) ~[spring-beans-5.1.15.RELEASE.jar:5.1.15.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.getOrderedBeansOfType(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:211) ~[spring-boot-2.1.14.RELEASE.jar:2.1.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.getOrderedBeansOfType(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:202) ~[spring-boot-2.1.14.RELEASE.jar:2.1.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.addServletContextInitializerBeans(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:96) ~[spring-boot-2.1.14.RELEASE.jar:2.1.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.<init>(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:85) ~[spring-boot-2.1.14.RELEASE.jar:2.1.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.getServletContextInitializerBeans(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:253) ~[spring-boot-2.1.14.RELEASE.jar:2.1.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.selfInitialize(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:227) ~[spring-boot-2.1.14.RELEASE.jar:2.1.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatStarter.onStartup(TomcatStarter.java:53) ~[spring-boot-2.1.14.RELEASE.jar:2.1.14.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5140) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:841) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:421) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:930) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:468) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:105) ~[spring-boot-2.1.14.RELEASE.jar:2.1.14.RELEASE]
    ... 13 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'simpleMeterRegistry' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/metrics/export/simple/SimpleMetricsExportAutoConfiguration.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/collect/Lists
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:601) ~[spring-beans-5.1.15.RELEASE.jar:5.1.15.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) ~[spring-beans-5.1.15.RELEASE.jar:5.1.15.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.15.RELEASE.jar:5.1.15.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226) ~[spring-beans-5.1.15.RELEASE.jar:5.1.15.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.15.RELEASE.jar:5.1.15.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.15.RELEASE.jar:5.1.15.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:277) ~[spring-beans-5.1.15.RELEASE.jar:5.1.15.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1271) ~[spring-beans-5.1.15.RELEASE.jar:5.1.15.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1191) ~[spring-beans-5.1.15.RELEASE.jar:5.1.15.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:857) ~[spring-beans-5.1.15.RELEASE.jar:5.1.15.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:760) ~[spring-beans-5.1.15.RELEASE.jar:5.1.15.RELEASE]
    ... 53 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/collect/Lists
    at com.netflix.config.PropertyWrapper.<init>(PropertyWrapper.java:41) ~[archaius-core-0.7.6.jar:0.7.6]
    at com.netflix.hystrix.strategy.properties.archaius.HystrixDynamicPropertiesArchaius$ArchaiusDynamicProperty.<init>(HystrixDynamicPropertiesArchaius.java:62) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.18.jar:1.5.18]
    at com.netflix.hystrix.strategy.properties.archaius.HystrixDynamicPropertiesArchaius$StringDynamicProperty.<init>(HystrixDynamicPropertiesArchaius.java:73) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.18.jar:1.5.18]
    at com.netflix.hystrix.strategy.properties.archaius.HystrixDynamicPropertiesArchaius.getString(HystrixDynamicPropertiesArchaius.java:34) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.18.jar:1.5.18]
    at com.netflix.hystrix.strategy.HystrixPlugins.getPluginImplementationViaProperties(HystrixPlugins.java:344) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.18.jar:1.5.18]
    at com.netflix.hystrix.strategy.HystrixPlugins.getPluginImplementation(HystrixPlugins.java:334) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.18.jar:1.5.18]
    at com.netflix.hystrix.strategy.HystrixPlugins.getEventNotifier(HystrixPlugins.java:129) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.18.jar:1.5.18]
    at io.micrometer.core.instrument.binder.hystrix.HystrixMetricsBinder.bindTo(HystrixMetricsBinder.java:36) ~[micrometer-core-1.1.13.jar:1.1.13]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.metrics.MeterRegistryConfigurer.lambda$addBinders$1(MeterRegistryConfigurer.java:84) ~[spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure-2.1.14.RELEASE.jar:2.1.14.RELEASE]
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:184) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.util.stream.SortedOps$RefSortingSink.end(SortedOps.java:390) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.util.stream.Sink$ChainedReference.end(Sink.java:258) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.util.stream.Sink$ChainedReference.end(Sink.java:258) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:482) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:151) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:174) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:418) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.metrics.MeterRegistryConfigurer.addBinders(MeterRegistryConfigurer.java:84) ~[spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure-2.1.14.RELEASE.jar:2.1.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.metrics.MeterRegistryConfigurer.configure(MeterRegistryConfigurer.java:66) ~[spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure-2.1.14.RELEASE.jar:2.1.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.metrics.MeterRegistryPostProcessor.postProcessAfterInitialization(MeterRegistryPostProcessor.java:64) ~[spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure-2.1.14.RELEASE.jar:2.1.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:429) ~[spring-beans-5.1.15.RELEASE.jar:5.1.15.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1775) ~[spring-beans-5.1.15.RELEASE.jar:5.1.15.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593) ~[spring-beans-5.1.15.RELEASE.jar:5.1.15.RELEASE]
    ... 63 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.common.collect.Lists
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    ... 89 common frames omitted
```

**pom.xml file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.14.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.srik</groupId>
    <artifactId>naming-server-eureka</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>naming-server-eureka</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <maven-jar-plugin.version>3.1.1</maven-jar-plugin.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Greenwich.SR5</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**application.properties file:**

```
spring.application.name=naming-server-eureka
server.port=8300
eureka.client.register-with-eureka=false
eureka.client.fetch-registry=false
```

**Main method class:**

```
@SpringBootApplication

@EnableEurekaServer
public class NamingServerEurekaApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("spring.devtools.restart.enabled", "false");
        SpringApplication.run(NamingServerEurekaApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Comment: Well the `Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/collect/Lists` is telling you what is wrong (you are missing a dependency).

Comment: @M.Deinum, yes even i thought same and added following dependency \<groupId>com.google.guava</groupId><artifactId>guava</artifactId>version>29.0-jre</version> but still no luck, can you guide me in finding required dependency

Comment: The fact that you added that dependency doesn't mean you have other issues? ALso could be that the jar is corrupted. Try `mvn dependency:purge-local-repository` which will remove all dependencies and afterwards (when building) reload them. You might want to try first without the Guava dependency (ideally it should be pulled in automatically).

Answer (score 0):

it seems your problem because of using Lists whithout adding its dependency in maven
add the code blow to your pom:

```
    <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>29.0-jre</version>
</dependency>
```